# Replace using gsub in awk

Tags: awk

trying to do a gsub in awk.
I want to replace single space with underscore, but the adjoining characters are replaced

```
awk -F"  +" 'NF > 1  {gsub(/[[:alnum:]][ ][[:alnum:]]/, "_")}1' file
```

Input:

```
this is example

ca                                 bc           dec cat
251                          otg          op con
```

this is what I get:

```
this is example

ca                                 bc           de_at
251                          otg          o_on
```

Desired output:

```
this is example

ca                                 bc           dec_cat
251                          otg          op_con
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one area where (non-GNU) awk isn't the best tool for the job. I'd suggest using sed instead:

```
$ sed '/  / s/\([[:alnum:]]\) \([[:alnum:]]\)/\1_\2/g' file
this is example

ca                                 bc           dec_cat
251                          otg          op_con
```

This performs substitutions on lines containing 2 or more spaces, which is an equivalent condition to `NF > 1` given your field separator.

The key here is to capture the characters before and after the space and then use them in the replacement. This can be done in GNU awk too, using `gensub`:

```
$ gawk -F"  +" 'NF > 1 { $0 = gensub(/([[:alnum:]]) ([[:alnum:]])/, "\\1_\\2", 1) }1' file
this is example

ca                                 bc           dec_cat
251                          otg          op_con
```

`gensub` returns the result of the substitution, so it must be reassigned to `$0` in order to affect the output.

Comment: You could use `/  /` instead of `2,$` to filter for lines that have two or more fields given a `"  +"` field separator (two spaces in each; the comment layout swallows them). I'd consider using `perl -pe 's/\S\K (?=\S)/_/g if /  /'`, though (again, two spaces in `/  /`).

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the condition along the lines of your suggestion. The perl code you suggested looks like it does the job but I guess it depends on how strict the "alphanumeric" requirement is.

Comment: Ah, I didn't read carefully enough there. It's simple to fix, though: replace `\S` with `\w`.

Comment: Regarding the white space being swallowed, looks like it's the result of a "fix" for another issue: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272194/2088135 :)